# C++ reduce string memory usage

Tags: c++, string, memory

I need to store a lot of short strings with a constant length.
I noticed that a string object allocates 8 bytes, even if it holds some chars, which let me run into memory trouble.

Is there a way to tell C++ that it should allocate only n (constant) bytes for the string? Or do I have to use char arrays?

Comment: This is a matter of quality of implementation. Recent libstdc++ and libc++ strings use small-string optimization that doesn't allocate any memory at all.

Comment: Just in case you wonder, `sizeof(some_std_string_object) != some_std_string_object.length()`

Comment: This looks like a low level optimisation. C++ usages recomment to avoid such optimisation in early development stages and only use them when you are sure they are worth it, by profiling or memory usage measuring. You should hide implementation in a dedicated class using the least possible of string functionnalities, and at optimization time, look if replacing strings with char arrays is justified.

Comment: You might be a good candidate for [Boost.Flyweight](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/flyweight/doc/index.html) since there's often a lot of repetition in short strings--it could give you some extra memory savings.

Comment: Thx for recommendation, but it's a homework for university. It's not allowed to use non standard librarys

Comment: Can you quantify "a lot of" - unless you are storing millions of strings, why is this a problem? Since it is homework, why not just let it be inefficient a little. It's better than using raw char arrays. What is the actual "memory trouble"?

Answer (score 1):

Since the strings are constant size, you may want allocate a 2 dimensional array (each row is a string).  Allocate the array once, at initialization.  This is the most compact form.

If the quantity of strings is unknown, consider using a `std::vector` of arrays of character.  I recommend reserving a large size when the vector is created, to reduce the number or reallocations.

Also, ask yourself if the strings need to be stored in memory for the duration of the program.  Will you be accessing (searching) them?  Can the data be placed into a file or database?

Answer (score 0):

std::string does have the constructor that takes a char* and a size but some std::string implementations do not use small string optimisation so they always contain a pointer to the actual data which takes some space. If you use GCC it uses copy on write to save space which also requires a pointer. If there are many duplicates of the strings you could maybe save space by using a map or a set of strings to eliminate duplicates. Or you could just use a char array which is the most basic form with the lowest overhead but also less comfort.

Comment: AFAIK copy on write was used maybe in older libstdc++, today it disappeared in almost any standard library (also due to threading issues).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Nope, GCC up to and including 4.9 still uses COW according to http://info.prelert.com/blog/cpp-stdstring-implementations#summarytable

Answer (score 0):

A pointer and count is 8 bytes on a 32-bit system anyway.  It's hard to make a string be smaller than that.  A string with SSO will likely be *larger* than 8 bytes.  (Perhaps 4 bytes - 1 bit for the count.  1 bit to indicate small string or not.  12 bytes of small string buffer or 4 bytes pointer + 4 bytes capacity => A total of 16 bytes.)

If they are constant length (and given you probably don't need most of `std::string`'s functionality), you probably need to write your own text-id class.  (Probably with conversions to and from `std::string`.)

Possibly a suitable guide: https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2015/05/14/handling-short-codes-part-i/

Comment: You may notice a lot of "probably"s in the last para.  That is deliberate.